# React Admin - Create record and then update item

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a react admin app. When a user clicks a button, the user submitted item is approved and a parameter is changed on the item. The useCreate hook is then used to create a duplicate record in a second database. I need to wait for the useCreate hook to complete and then update the original record with the ID that resulted from the creation. I can't quite figure out how to do this.

Here is the code that creates a button that lets a user approve of the item and then carries out the update, creation, and needs to carry out the subsequent update.

```
const ApproveButton = ({ record }) => {
  const [approve] = useUpdate(
    "itemsubmission",
    record.id,
    { status: ItemStatusTypes["APPROVED"] },
    record
  );

  const [create] = useCreate("items", {
    isValid: true,
    name: record.title === null ? "" : record.title
  });

  const handleClick = (record) => {
    approve();
    const result = create();
    /* This is where I need to take the results of the create function and place the 
    /* resulting ID in the first record's database. The update is easy, but I don't 
    /* know how to wait for the create to end
  };

  return (
    <FlatButton
      label={EventStatusChangeTypes["APPROVED"]}
      type={"approve"}
      onClick={handleClick}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await, Promise. Example given with async/await

```
const handleClick = async (record) => {
    approve();
    const result = await create();
```

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: useUpdate, useCreate working fine?

Comment: Yes. Everything works fine. I don't think that useCreate returns a promise

Comment: then you don't need to wait

Comment: There has to be some way to get the data resulting from the create and then use it. That has to be a feature. I'm just not sure of the way to do it.

Comment: Have you solved in some way? I have a similar situation but with the addition of a ".map" function where "create" and "update" functions are.
1. Map function "reads" the array of element ids
2. Create new record on tableA
3. Using the new record id (from tableA) tableB is updated using tableA.id as foreign key related to tableB.id_A